# How to run Jupyter notebook on AWS instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, powershell, jupyter-notebook

## How to run Jupyter notebook on AWS instance, chmod 400 error

I want to run my jupyter notebooks in the cloud, ec2 AWS instance.

--

I'm following this tutorial:
https://www.codingforentrepreneurs.com/blog/jupyter-notebook-server-aws-ec2-aws-vpc

--

I have the Instance ec2 all set up as well as nginx.

--

### Problem is..

When typing `chmod 400 JupyterKey.pem` just work for MAC not Windowns Power shell

```
cd path/to/my/dev/folder/
chmod 400 JupyterKey.pem
ssh ubuntu@34.235.154.196 -i JupyterKey.pem


Error: The term 'chmod' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, cript, or operation
       category info: ObjectNotFound
        FullyQualifiedErrorId: Command notFoundException
```

Comment: Skip that. It is not important.

Answer (score 2):

AWS has a managed Jupyter Notebook service as part of [Amazon SageMaker](https://aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/).

SageMaker hosted notebook instances enable you to easily spin up a Jupyter Notebook with one click, with [pay per hour pricing](https://aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/pricing/) (similar to EC2 billing), and with the ability to easily upload your existing notebook directly onto the managed instance, all directly through the instance URL + AWS console.

Check out [this tutorial](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/gs-setup-working-env.html)  for a guide on getting started!

Comment: thank you @nmwalsh I will be running daily reports, so it mid get expensive for me. better try to set up since I will be not doing ML only simple calculations just automation basically

Comment: Once you've generated your notebook and it runs as desired from top to bottom, you have the option to export the code as a `.py` file. Depending on the task you're performing, you could build a recurring cloud function with AWS Lambda that would run for your desired frequency (ie: once per day) and outputs the report (PDF, images, etc) to Amazon S3 to persist them. Otherwise, you can provision and shut down the hosted notebook instance if you're set on using a notebook each time and want to minimize costs.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same permission problem and could fix it by running the following command in the Amazon Machine Image Linux:

```
sudo chown user:user ~/certs/mycert.pem
```